# Adding text to a boxplot that does not have a numbered axes

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I am interested in labeling my boxplot with the letter A in the top left corner, but because I have a categorical X axis comparing seasons (summer vs winter), I am unable to give coordinates for my added text. How do you add text to a boxplot with a categorical axis?

This is what I've tried, which doesn't work:

```
`boxplot(LogTHg~Season, data = HgSIS, xlab= "Season", ylab= "LogTHg", text ("topleft", "A"))'
```

Comment: One approach is to add a legend there, such as: `legend("topleft", "A", bty = "n")`

Answer (score 0):

Three points:

1. As [Ben writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708444/adding-text-to-a-boxplot-that-does-not-have-a-numbered-axes#comment116177695_65708444), you can add a `legend` with `x="topleft"`. The `inset` parameter allows you to separate it from the top and left boundaries.
2. If you call `boxplot()` with a formula object that has a factor-like right hand side, then R will put the first boxplot over the horizontal coordinate 1, the second over 2 and so forth. Which still doesn't tell you what the exact coordinates of the top left corner of the plotting region are, but you can at least do a couple of things. Like putting labels above each separate boxplot.
3. Relatedly, you can use the `xlim` parameter for `boxplot()` to control the horizontal spacing. For instance, if you use `xlim=c(0,3)`, then you *know* that you can put something at horizontal coordinate 0. And the same with `ylim`.